# semirings and basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be a semiring of subsets of a nonempty set $X$. What additional requirements must be satisfied for $S$ to be a base for a topology on $X$?

Prove that if such is the case, then each member of $S$ is both open and closed in this topology. What about all the open sets, are they closed too?

Comment: What are the operations on $S$?

Comment: What do you mean with operations on S?

Comment: I what to know that every open set (every topology element) is closed?if not,what is an example?

Answer (score 1):

There are several equivalent definitions of *semiring of sets*. I will use the definition at [**link 1**](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semiring_of_Sets)

(**I**) It is sufficient that a semiring $S$  of subsets of a set $X$ to cover the set $X$  (i.e. $\bigcup S = X$) for $S$ to be base of a topological space on $X$.

*Proof.*

Suppose $S$ is such a semiring which covers  $X.\ $

A necessary and sufficient condition for a set $B$ of subsets of a set $X$ to be a base of a topological space on $X$ is to satisfy two conditions:

1. $B$ covers  $X.\ $
2. Let $b_1, b_2$ be elements of $B$ and let $I$ be their intersection. Then for each $x$ in $I$, there is an element $b_3$ of $B$ containing $x$ and contained in $I$.

(check this [**link 2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology))).

Since $S$ satisfies 1., it remains to prove that $S$ satisfies 2.

Let  $b_1, b_2$ be elements of $S$, $I$ be their intersection, and $x$ be in $I$.  Since $S$ is a semiring, it is $\cap-$`++`stable, and thus $I$ is in $S$, and 2. is satisfied.

(**II**). If the semiring $S$  of subsets of $X$ covers the set $X$, and thus, it is a base of a topology $T$ on $X$, then each member $s$ of $S$ is both close and open.

*Proof.*

Let  $s$ be member of $S. \ $ According the definition at [**link 1**](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semiring_of_Sets), (3'), $s$ is a union of a finite number of  disjoint members of $S$ (take  $A =s$, and $B = \emptyset$). Since $S$ is the base of topology $T$, this union of open sets is also an open set in $T$.

Now prove that $s$ is a closed set, i.e  ($X \setminus s$) is an open set in $T$. Use again [**link 1**](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semiring_of_Sets), (3'), now setting $A = X$ and $B = s$, and get that $X \setminus s$ is a union of a finite number of  disjoint members of $S$. Since $S$ is the base of topology $T$, this union of open sets is also an open set.

We got that in the topology generated by a semiring of subsets of a set,which covers this set,  all open sets are also closed and conversely (I did not know this).

The sets of a topological space which ar both open and closed, are called **clopen**. Notice these facts:

. A topological space $X$ is discrete if and only if all of its subsets are clopen.

. Using the union and intersection as operations, the clopen subsets of a given topological space $X$ form a Boolean algebra. Every Boolean algebra can be obtained in this way from a suitable topological space: see Stone's representation theorem for Boolean algebras.

You can find these facts at [link 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set).

Comment: Thanks a lot.                                                  We understand that every set of S(semigroup)is clopen.but I think that it is not necessary true for the sets of T\S,because an arbitrary intersection of open sets is not open,but I can not find an example

Comment: For an arbitrary topology, an arbitrary intersection of open sets may not be open, but for a topology T which is generated by a semiring of sets, such an intersection is always open. Such a topology is called "discrete" - it is a kind of topology which might not be very interesting.  Let us put it in other words. A topology is a set of sets stable under finite intersections and arbitrary unions. A discrete topology is a set of sets stable under arbitrary intersections and arbitrary unions.

Comment: How can we prove it?I mean how can directly show that an arbitrary A in T\S is closed?

Comment: Aha, now I noticed. In my answer I replied to your first two questions, but misread the third and thought that II also replies to it. Actually, I don't know the answer to your third question, but I think that probably a counterexample can be found. Also pls disrigard my comment - it was written in haste.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I found an example.If S={[a,b):a&b are real},then we can show that X\{x} is open but {x} is not open,So X\{x} is not closed(X is the set of real numbers).What do you think about it?

Comment: Is the set of open intervals of a real line a semiring? I cannot prove on short notice that it is not, because I never before worked with semirings, but it does not look to be a semiring (see (3') in definition of the semiring).

Comment: The intervals are [a,b),so S is a semiring.you can see this in Aliprantis book page 96 example 12.9

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is a semiring and, thus, this is a counterexample.