# Condtions to make a semiring a base for a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, self-learning

In the book "Principles of Real Analysis" by Aliprantis and Burkinshaw I found the following exercise:

> Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a semiring of subsets of a nonempty set $X$. What additional requirements must be satisfied for $\mathcal{S}$ in order to be a base for a topology on $X$?
>
> Prove that if such is the case, the each member of $\mathcal{S}$ is both open and closed in this topology?

Recall the definition of **semiring** $\mathcal{S}$, as the collection of subsets of a given space $X$ such that:
1. $\varnothing \in \mathcal{S}$;
2. for all $A, B \in \mathcal{S}$, $A \cap B  \in \mathcal{S}$;
3. for all $A, B \in \mathcal{S}$, there exists  $C_1, \dots, C_n \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $A \setminus B  = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}  C_k$.

My answer is that it is enough to have that, for every $x \in X$, $\{ x \} \in \mathcal{S}$.

Interestingly, at least to me, I found in the companion book "Problems in Real Analysis", that the solutions is that $\mathcal{S}$ is a base if and only if $\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{S}} A = X$.

Now the question is, *are the two answers equivalent*?

I have the feeling that the one in the book is apparently less demanding than my condition, but they should really be the same. *Am I right?*

As always, thank you for your time.
Any feedback is most welcome.

Comment: Could you remind us the definition of a *semiring of subsets*?

Comment: Very close to the question [semirings and basis of a topology](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878196/semirings-and-basis-of-a-topology?rq=1)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: You are right when you write that they are close. They are not a duplicate, though. Indeed, my focus is on the equivalency of my answer to the answer that can be found in the body of my question (and in the link you provided). Btw, thank for the link.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: I added the definition of semiring.

Comment: Did I miss something? If you take $\mathcal{S} = \{ \emptyset, X\}$, then $\mathcal{S}$ is a semiring (and even a Boolean algebra) and a topology (the trivial one). However, unless $|X| = 1$, $\mathcal{S}$ does not contain the singletons.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Don't worry, it's definitely not you that is missing something, and I perfectly see your example! Still, does it mean in the end that my "solution" is simply way to strong to get what we want, even if the result is the same?